# How can I draw superscript for node in dot language?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want draw a superscript **on Node** in using of dot language.

Is this possible?

- If yes, how can I do this?
- If no, what tools should I ues to get graph like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xlabel` attribute creates [an external label for a node or edge](http://graphviz.org/content/attrs#dxlabel). The following will get you part of the way there. Once you have your entire graph created you can play with spacing to avoid overlaps.

```
graph {
    node [shape = circle];
    edge [style = dashed; minlen = 2];
    NOP [style = dashed; xlabel = "0"];
    node [label = "*"]; n1 n2 n3 n6 n8;
    n1 [xlabel = "1"];
    n2 [xlabel = "2"];
    n3 [xlabel = "3"];
    n6 [xlabel = "6"];
    n8 [xlabel = "8"];
    n10 [xlabel = "10"];
    NOP -- n1;
    NOP -- n2;
    NOP -- n3;
    NOP -- n6;
    NOP -- n8;
    n10 [label = "+"];
    NOP -- n10;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also experiment with the [headlabel](http://graphviz.org/content/attrs#dheadlabel) and [taillabel](http://graphviz.org/content/attrs#dtaillabel) edge attributes.